# 3 display setup with HD6950

Tags: display, amd-radeon, multiple-monitors

I'm considering buying a HD6950 so I can run 3 screens.  Can I connect a monitor to each of the DVI ports and the third to the HDMI port?  If not, will I have to get an active adapter and use a display port to DVI for one of them?

I'm trying to connecting two 22 inch LED monitors and one 3D HDTV.

Comment: Really should be asked on meta (probably has been, actually) but FYI - the "This message does not meet our quality standards" error generally is because of gross lack of capitalization, punctuation, etc.  Try writing proper English and you shouldn't need to lengthen your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Flex edition of the Radeon HD6950 can use 3 monitors in the way you want, but otherwise, the HDMI output is shared with one of the DVI outputs, meaning you would only be able to have two monitors working at any one time, in any combination of the three ports.

Now, the Flex editions, that also have DP (specific Display Port 1.2) can potentially be daisy chained for up to 6 displays...

[image]

This [forum post](http://www.rage3d.com/board/showpost.php?p=1336800241&postcount=13) seems to explain it in better detail...

> Basically it works like this, the display unit can control up to 6 outputs, that's all built into the gpu, it also has 2 clock signal generators built in.  Each display port connection uses 1 output, each vga/hdmi/dvi also uses one output but also need one clock signal. (this is why you need an active dp adaptor as it needs to generate a clock signal)

and the [whole thread](http://www.rage3d.com/board/showthread.php?t=33985452) it comes from does provide multiple configuration options that may enable you to get three monitors (using the DP1.2 with DVI converters, etc.)